# Simple Linear Regression with Ranked Data (scale 0-100), scatterplots look wrong?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression

I'm sure this is an incredibly basic question to be asking on this forum, so I apologise in advance for that.
I'm completely new to statistics. I have a dataset of interval data organised as follows: wine quality (on a scale from 0-100 by intervals of 10), sulphates (g(potassium sulphate)/dm3 - all of these fall between 0.330 and 2.00), and alcohol content (%, all of these fall between 8.4% and 14.9%). N = 1499.
My aim is to predict whether sulphates and alcohol content are a good predictor of wine quality.
To do this, I want to conduct a correlation analysis and a simple linear regression analysis.
The variable tripping me up a lot is wine quality. My scatterplots all look like this:
[A scatterplot with units vertically "stacked" over the x-axis points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVov2.png) And I don't know why.
I've done a linear regression analysis but not with these kinds of variables.

I'm mostly just wondering why my scatterplots look like that and any tips on how to handle the wine quality variable. Thank you.

EDIT FOR CLARIFICATION: My basic questions are: (1) is simple linear regression the correct approach for this? i.e. Wine Quality = β0 + β1(Alcohol Content) + ε and Wine Quality = β0 + β1(Sulphates) + ε and (2) Is there any way to get my scatterplots to look normal?

Comment: The $x$ axis comes in intervals of $10$, so all the points are arranged on vertical lines with a spacing of $10$ (the lines corresponding to the possible values of $x$). This isn't a problem for regression analysis. Though a separate thing which you might want to account for is attenuation bias, as presumably there is uncertainty in the measurement of wine quality.

Comment: Thank you for responding! Is there any way to change this? Also, what do you mean that this isn't a problem for regression analysis?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Edited main post for clarification. Thanks!

Comment: It is usual to plot the dependent variable (here wine quality) on the $y$ axis rather than the $x$ axis, but this will not affect your discreteness issue

Comment: I suspect your model is closer to being $\text{Wine Quality }= [β_0 + β_1(\text{Alcohol Content}) + β_2(\text{Sulphates}) + ε]$, combing the two explanatory variables into one model, where $[\cdots]$ means rounding to a multiple of $10$.  If you ignore the rounding, you can use linear regression to get fitted values; it would then be worth plotting residuals (actual values minus fitted values) against fitted values and seeing what you see there (there will be diagonal lines resulting from the rounding but less overlap than your current chart)

Comment: In my previous comment I misunderstood what the independent variable is. So error in wine quality can't cause attenuation bias. You can still do a simple linear regression with rounded values. The rounding error just gets absorbed into $\varepsilon$. As long as other sources of uncertainty are significantly larger, for any given values of the independent variables, the dependent variable is about as likely to be rounded up as rounded down. This means the rounding error isn't correlated with the dependent variables. So $\varepsilon$ including it still meets the criteria for a valid regression.